# Dictionary object not deleting when used alongside another dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone shed any light on why when I run two dictionaries together they don't work?

My son had some homework which involved building a deck of shuffled cards.  I gave him two methods: the first was to build the deck randomly and the second was to first build a deck and then randomly choose cards from the first deck and build a second deck from that.

So I used a quick for-next loop to construct the starting deck going from 1-52 and then starting with a new empty dictionary loop until the new dictionary contains all 52 cards.
This I do by randomly picking a card from the original deck and then adding it to the new deck and then removing it from the original deck.

However I am consistently seeing over 20 cards left in the original deck and duplicates in the new deck.

If I do it using a collection as the Original deck and a dictionary as the shuffled deck it works every time!

So any ideas?  Ive had this a couple of times when trying to use two dictionaries together.

Code of both ideas.  The RetCard function just works out the name of the card.

```
Public Sub CardBuild1()
  Dim dDeck As Dictionary
  Dim dShuffled As Dictionary
  Dim lCard As Long, lCards As Long
  Dim lPick As Long, lVal As Long, lIndex As Long
  Dim sCard As String
  Dim vItems As Variant

  Set dDeck = New Dictionary

  For lCard = 1 To 52
    dDeck.Add lCard, lCard
  Next lCard

  Set dShuffled = New Dictionary
  lIndex = 1
  Do Until dShuffled.Count = 52
    lCards = dDeck.Count
    lPick = Int((lCards) * Rnd()) + 1
    lVal = dDeck(lPick)

    sCard = RetCard(lVal)
    dShuffled.Add lIndex, sCard

    lIndex = lIndex + 1
    dDeck.Remove lPick

  Loop

  vItems = Application.Transpose(dShuffled.Items)
  Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vItems, 1), 1) = vItems
End Sub

Public Sub CardBuild2()
  Dim cDeck As Collection
  Dim dShuffled As Dictionary
  Dim lPick As Long

  Set cDeck = New Collection

  For lPick = 1 To 52
    cDeck.Add lPick
  Next lPick

  Set dShuffled = New Dictionary
  Do Until dShuffled.Count = 52
    lPick = Int((cDeck.Count) * Rnd()) + 1
    dShuffled(dShuffled.Count) = RetCard(cDeck(lPick))
    cDeck.Remove lPick
  Loop

  Cells(1, 1).Resize(52, 1) = Application.Transpose(dShuffled.Items)

End Sub

Private Function RetCard(lIndex As Long) As String
  Dim lSuit As Long, lCard As Long
  Dim sSuit As String

  lSuit = ((lIndex - 1) \ 13) + 1
  lCard = ((lIndex - 1) Mod 13) + 1

  sSuit = Choose(lSuit, "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades")
  RetCard = Switch(lCard = 1, "Ace", lCard > 1 And lCard < 11, lCard, lCard = 11, "Jack", lCard = 12, "Queen", lCard = 13, "King") & " of " & sSuit

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple. Whenever you want to pick a random card from the **remaining** deck you are using `lPick = Int((cDeck.Count) * Rnd()) + 1` to select a number from 1 to `remainingDeck.Count` and then you wish to tell VBA to count (from the top of the deck) n-items downs and pick this random card from the remaining deck. This you wish to achieve with the following line of code:

```
lVal = dDeck(lPick)
```

But that's not what this line of code means. Instead you are telling VBA to get the `lPick` card from the original (52-cards) deck. And if that card is not found (because it has been already removed) then an empty card is added.

Maybe this is easier to understand with the following illustration. First we have the following cards in the deck:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
```

But when I remove then the 8th card from the deck (which is also the card with the face value 8) I will have this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7   9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
```

If `lPick = Int((cDeck.Count) * Rnd()) + 1` then (randomly) happens to be 8 again then the card with the face value 8 (**not** the 8th card) is missing and cannot be added to the shuffled deck nor can it be removed from the old deck.

So, if you wish to tell VBA instead that you want to pick the 8th card from the remaining deck (which would be in the above example the number 9) then you'd have to adjust your code as follows:

```
Public Sub CardBuild1()
  Dim dDeck As Dictionary
  Dim dShuffled As Dictionary
  Dim lCard As Long, lCards As Long
  Dim lPick As Long, lVal As Long, lIndex As Long
  Dim sCard As String
  Dim vItems As Variant

  Set dDeck = New Dictionary

  For lCard = 1 To 52
    dDeck.Add lCard, lCard
  Next lCard


  Set dShuffled = New Dictionary
  lIndex = 1
  Do Until dShuffled.Count = 52
    lCards = dDeck.Count
    lPick = Int((lCards) * Rnd())    'by default 0-based and thus no longer +1 here
    lVal = dDeck.Items(lPick)        'taking the nth card from the top

    sCard = RetCard(lVal)
    dShuffled.Add lIndex, sCard

    lIndex = lIndex + 1
    dDeck.Remove (dDeck.Items(lPick))

  Loop

  vItems = Application.Transpose(dShuffled.Items)
  Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vItems, 1), 1) = vItems
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks....I'm not sure where my head was for that...and yes the idea was to do as you pointed out in the example of 8, but I was clearly making a mistake with the way I used keys.

Ive put the solution I settled with below.  Made a slight change as the remove didn't work using the Items but did with the Keys

Answer (score 1):

in the first sub lpick is the value of the card : you should check if the card lpick is still in the deck. In the second sub lpick is the position (index) of the value (you don't have duplicates), this explains the difference between the 2 subs.

Comment: The code in the first and second is identical other than the fact I thought that setting out each stage might solve the problem. (It didn't)

I am relying on the key to hold the position of the card and so although they start off on parity once the first card has been drawn (unless card 52) the cards will move down the line. ie if I draw card 33 that will will be the value 33, however once deleted card 33 will now be 34 and card 34 will be 35 etc etc.

The problem is that the remove method on dDeck isn't consistently removing the record.

Comment: You and I have pretty much the same answer. Yet, you might want to add a bit more of an explanation (otherwise JontyR would have understood you) and - more importantly - how to resolve the problem. Still, *(+1)* from my side for giving an answer one minute before me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub CardBuild1()
  Dim dDeck As Dictionary
  Dim dShuffled As Dictionary
  Dim lCard As Long, lCards As Long
  Dim lPick As Long, lVal As Long, lIndex As Long
  Dim sCard As String
  Dim vItems As Variant

  Set dDeck = New Dictionary

  For lCard = 1 To 52
    dDeck(dDeck.Count) = lCard
  Next lCard

  Set dShuffled = New Dictionary
  lIndex = 1
  Do Until dShuffled.Count = 52
    lCards = dDeck.Count
    lPick = Int((lCards) * Rnd())
    lVal = dDeck.Items(lPick)

    Debug.Print lPick & vbTab & lVal
    vItems = dDeck.Items

    sCard = RetCard(lVal)
    dShuffled.Add lIndex, sCard

    lIndex = lIndex + 1
    dDeck.Remove dDeck.Keys(lPick)
    If dDeck.Count >= lCards Then Stop
  Loop

  vItems = Application.Transpose(dShuffled.Items)
  Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vItems, 1), 1).Clear
  Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vItems, 1), 1) = vItems
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be actually done with very little code, as follows:

```
Public Sub CardBuild1()
    Dim dShuffled As Dictionary

    Set dShuffled = New Dictionary
    With dShuffled '<--| reference your new dictionary
        Do Until .Count = 52
            .Item(Int(52 * Rnd())) = 1 '<--| this will add new item to referenced dictionary if the key (the random number between 1 and 52) is not already there
        Loop
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys) '<--| write directly 'Keys' array into wanted range 
    End With
End Sub
```

---

you can then use the *core* of the above code to make a `Function` returning a shuffled deck as a `Dictionary` object:

```
Function GetShuffledDeck() As Dictionary
    Dim tempDict As Dictionary

    Set tempDict = New Dictionary
    With tempDict
        Do Until .Count = 52
            .Item(Int(52 * Rnd())) = 1
        Loop
    End With
    Set GetShuffledDeck = tempDict
End Function
```

which you'd exploit in your *main* code as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim dShuffled As Dictionary
    Set dShuffled = GetShuffledDeck '<--| use your 'Function' to return a shuffled deck as a dictionary object

    With dShuffled 
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

one (maybe) last step could be dealing with a *dynamic* number of card:

```
Function GetDynamicShuffledDeck(Optional nCards As Long) As Dictionary
    Dim tempDict As Dictionary

    If nCards <= 0 Then nCards = 52 '<--| if calling sub passed an invalid numbre of cards or no numbre at all then assume 52 cards
    Set tempDict = New Dictionary
    With tempDict
        Do Until .Count = nCards
            .Item(Int(nCards * Rnd())) = 1
        Loop
    End With
    Set GetDynamicShuffledDeck = tempDict
End Function
```

which would be called by your *main* sub as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim dShuffled As Dictionary

    Set dShuffled = GetDynamicShuffledDeck 40  '<--| a 40 cards deck will be returned

    Set dShuffled = GetDynamicShuffledDeck '<--| no 'nCards' argument passed -> a 52 cards deck will be returned


    With dShuffled
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach to adding items to the dictionary.  My first method was to do something similar and just use the .Exists, but this negates that.

However my thoughts were that the time taken to find the last elements of the dictionary could take a long time if the random number keeps picking ones already within the deck.

Which is why I started with an "Unshuffled" Deck and then effectively shuffled them.  So by picking a random number between 0 and the number of cards-1 left in the deck it should be quicker.

Comment: _"it should be quicker"_ : you'd be surprised by actual performance of a code with all that `Add` and `Remove`. You could make some performance tests and yet with only 52 elements to deal with I'd go with a shorted code

Answer (score 1):

Tangential, but if you want to expose your son to methods for shuffling a deck, you could also show him the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) shuffle:

```
Sub FisherYates(deck As Variant)
    'assumes that deck is a 1-based array
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim temp As Variant

    n = UBound(deck)
    For i = n To 2 Step -1
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, i - 1)
        temp = deck(i)
        deck(i) = deck(j)
        deck(j) = temp
    Next i
End Sub
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim d As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim d(1 To 52)
    For i = 1 To 52
        d(i) = i
    Next i

    FisherYates d
    Debug.Print Join(d, ",")
End Sub
```

With typical output:

```
52,25,4,29,24,1,40,50,10,27,7,35,37,15,39,47,41,23,5,19,45,13,51,17,9,32,11,49,26,21,20,36,34,43,28,2,38,44,31,12,18,8,30,33,42,48,46,3,22,14,6,16
```